# Access to attribute in rasterlayer in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, regression

I read an ADF file in R:

```
 kommuner <- raster( "../../../10-Data/Kommunne_i_Norge_2000/Kommuner2000_100m_100m/100x100_2k/w001001.adf" )
```

It contains three attributes:

```
> kommuner
```

> class       : RasterLayer
>
> dimensions  : 14903, 11906, 177435118  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>
> resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
>
> extent      : -75900, 1114700, 6449500, 7939800  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>
> coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
>
> data source : /path_to/w001001.adf
>
> names       : w001001
>
> values      : 1, 435  (min, max)
>
> attributes  :
>
> ```
>    ID COUNT  OBJ
> ```
>
> from:   1 63390 0101
>
> to  : 435 26048 0903

Now, the question is how I can access the OBJ feature in an easy way. By easy I mean something similar to how I would access a column in a data frame, such as DF$OBJ. Could you help?

Secondly, I would like to create a new attribute that is linked to OBJ. Let's call it NI. How can I create the NI attribute, say, let NI = 4 + OBJ * 5?

Lastly, I would like to run a regression with the NI feature in this kommuner variable, which is the y-variable, against a number of other features in other variables. Could you provide an example so that I can imitate?

Comment: The guideline is one question per post.

Comment: values(kommuner) will give all values in a matrix. Try as.data.frame(kommuner) for a different form, and check out ?extract and ?cellFromXY for more abstract methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can access this table via `levels`:

```
> levels(r)
[[1]]
   ID OID Value    Count LC_Code         Land_Cover    Area_Ha
1   0   0     0 25615512     255            No Data 2305400.00
2   1   1     1  1287546       1       Dense Forest  115879.00
3   2   2     2   525368       2    Moderate Forest   47283.10
4   3   3     3  2993504       3      Sparse Forest  269415.00
```

Read `?raster::levels` for more.

If you want to modify it, fit models with it, etc, you can possibly modify it in-place, but it might be easier to just get it out, play with it, and put it back when you're done:

```
> z = levels(r)[[1]]
```

Create a new variable in `z`:

```
> z$r = z$Area_Ha/z$Count
> head(z)
  ID OID Value    Count LC_Code       Land_Cover    Area_Ha          r
1  0   0     0 25615512     255          No Data 2305400.00 0.09000015
2  1   1     1  1287546       1     Dense Forest  115879.00 0.08999989
3  2   2     2   525368       2  Moderate Forest   47283.10 0.08999996
4  3   3     3  2993504       3    Sparse Forest  269415.00 0.08999988
5  4   4     4        3      20         Woodland       0.27 0.09000000
6  5   5     5   349569      31 Closed Grassland   31461.20 0.08999997
```

Stick it back in:

```
> levels(r)[[1]]=z
> levels(r)
[[1]]
   ID OID Value    Count LC_Code         Land_Cover    Area_Ha          r
1   0   0     0 25615512     255            No Data 2305400.00 0.09000015
2   1   1     1  1287546       1       Dense Forest  115879.00 0.08999989
3   2   2     2   525368       2    Moderate Forest   47283.10 0.08999996
4   3   3     3  2993504       3      Sparse Forest  269415.00 0.08999988
```

Notice its a list of length one, because (I think) I have a single-layer raster. It might be a longer list if you have a `RasterStack`.